# Return in else branch of void function

Tags: java

Is it good or bad practice to have an else branch which only returns in a function that returns type void? Such as this code:

```
public void myFunc() {
  if (<some condition>) {
      //run some code
  } else {
      return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the else block?

Comment: Sorry, in the else block I mean to type "return;" NOT "return void;"

Comment: it is bad practice because you add code that effectively does nothing

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, thanks for all the quick replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this else statement is not required if you are not doing any operation.
The else statement is basically used to carry out an operation, if the condition of if do not met.**The best practice is not to write the else statement, if you are not doing any operation.**

```
public void myFunc() {
  if (<some condition>) {
      //call FunctionA();
  } else {
      //call FunctionB();
  }
}
```

In the above case, the use of else is valid. But if you are not doing any operation, then the statement is useless. Please read **Clean Code Book by Robert Cecil Martin**. It will help you in writing clean code.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this topic is **opinion based**, you will probably see many different preferences from user to user.

For **readability** and **maintainability** you should try to *reduce the complexity* of your code. Therefore you want to also reduce the **nesting**. Thus my prefered variant would be:

```
public void myFunc() {
    // Directly leave if condition does not hold
    if (!condition) {
        return;
    }

    // Now do the rest of the code
}
```

If you want to stick to your current variant then I would suggest to just drop the `else` part because it just aggravates the readability in my opinion, so:

```
public void myFunc() {
    if (condition) {
        // Do something
    }

    // You can always leave a comment if you think
    // that helps a reader, so you can put "Do nothing
    // if condition does not hold" here
}
```

However as said, I personally prefer the first variant because it reduces the nesting of the overall code.

Answer (score -1):

From the [`java.lang.Void` class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

> The `Void` class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the `Class` object representing the Java keyword `void`.

So any of the following would suffice:

- Parameterizing with `Object` and returning `new Object()` or `null`.
- Parameterizing with `Void` and returning `null`.
- Parameterizing with a `NullObject` of yours.

You can't make this method `void`, and anything else returns something. Since that something is ignored, you can return anything.